# find item in list , and get other item from other list at same location using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class where it has a collection of list. I want to search a parameter inside one of the list. So the location that I found the list, I want to get at the same location at other list in the same class...

How to achieve this?

```
void Main()
{
    var myListCollectionObj = new myListCollection();

    Console.WriteLine(myListCollectionObj.firstList);
    Console.WriteLine(myListCollectionObj.secondList);
    Console.WriteLine(myListCollectionObj.thirdList);

    var testFirstList = myListCollectionObj.firstList.Where(x => x == 3); //then i want to get "33", and 333 from secondList and thirdList respectively

    Console.WriteLine(testFirstList);

}

class myListCollection
{
    public List<int> firstList = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    public List<string> secondList = new List<string>(){ "11", "22", "33", "44", "55"};
    public List<int> thirdList = new List<int>(){ 111, 222, 333, 444, 555};

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct me if i am wrong are you looking for the index of the item you searched in first list and then use the same index to retrieve from other list

If yes 
Try this

```
var testFirstList = myListCollectionObj.firstList.Where(x => x == 3).FirstOrDefault(); //then i want to get "33", and 333 from secondList and thirdList respectively
var index = myListCollectionObj.firstList.IndexOf(testFirstList);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int index = myListCollectionObj.firstList.IndexOf(3);
string elem2;
int elem3;

if (index >= 0 && index < myListCollectionObj.secondList.Length)
  elem2 = myListCollectionObj.secondList[index]

if (index >= 0 && index < myListCollectionObj.thirdList.Length)
  elem3 = myListCollectionObj.thirdList[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ for that, only `List<T>`'s own `IndexOf()` method and indexer property:

```
int index = myListCollectionObj.firstList.IndexOf(3);
string secondValue = myListCollectionObj.secondList[index];
int thirdValue = myListCollectionObj.thirdList[index];
```

You may want to add error handling: if `3` is not contained in `firstList`, an index of `-1` is returned by `IndexOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way if there are more than one `3` values would be using simple `for` loop:

```
var testFirstList = new List<int>();
var testSecondList = new List<string>();
var testThirdList = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < myListCollectionObj.firstList.Length; ++i) {
    if (myListCollectionObj.firstList[i] == 3) {
        testFirstList.Add(myListCollectionObj.firstList[i]);
        testSecondList.Add(myListCollectionObj.secondList[i]);
        testThirdList.Add(myListCollectionObj.thirdList[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good guideline is that if you find yourself combining indices and LINQ, you probably have other options available.  In this case, a good alternative would be using `Zip`

This approach  lets you combine the 3 collections and act upon the resulting zipped collection as a single entity such that indices are no longer directly required.

```
var result = firstList.Zip(
     secondList.Zip(thirdList,
         (b, c) => new { b, c }),
         (a, b) => new { Value1 = a, Value2 = b.b, Value3 = b.c })
     .Where(x => x.Value1 == 3).ToList();

result.ForEach(v => Console.WriteLine(v));
```